# Duplication of Data in View php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to display a list of students with their corresponding exam keys. But my code duplicates the data and the exam keys are assigned to the wrong students (see the picture what I mean). Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code? I'm guessing that it has something to do with my model but I don't know what to change.

[Duplicate Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cB3Pz.png)

And Here are my code.

Controller

```
public function loadExamKey($examNo){
    $this->load->model('exam_model');
    $data = $this->addExamKey($examNo);
    $data = $this->exam_logs($examNo);

    $data['examKey'] = $this->exam_model->displayExamKeys($examNo);
    $this->load->view('exam_key', $data);
}
```

Model

```
public function displayExamKeys($examNo){

        $this->db->select('student.lastName');
        $this->db->select('student.firstName');
        $this->db->select('student.middleName');
        $this->db->select('student.student_no');
        $this->db->select('keys.exam_key');
        $this->db->from('student');
        $this->db->join('keys', 'student.course_id = keys.course_id');
        $this->db->where('exam_no', "$examNo");

        $query = $this->db->get();

        if($query->num_rows() > 0){
            return $query->result();
        }
        else
            return false;
```

View

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-advance table-hover">
                       <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <th><i class="">Student Number</th>
                            <th><i class=""></i> Name</th>
                            <th><i class=""></i> Exam Key</th>

                          </tr>
                <?php

               if($examKey != NULL){
                foreach ($examKey as $row) {
                  echo '<tr>';
                  echo '<td>'.$row->student_no.'</td>';
                  echo '<td>'.$row->lastName.",".$row->firstName." ".$row->middleName.'</td>';
                  echo '<td>'.$row->exam_key.'</td>';

                  echo '<tr>';
                }

               }
```

I am using php codeigniter and postgresql. I just started learning this and I'm a bit confuse.

Comment: try this line after $this->db->where('exam_no', "$examNo");                 $this->db->group_by('exam_no');

Comment: @GeordyJames it doesn't work either and I got error : Message: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: column "student.lastName" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function LINE 1: SELECT "student"."lastName", "student"."firstName", "student... ^

Comment: Can you post all attributes (all column fields) of students table and keys table along with question

Comment: STUDENT(lastName, firstName, middleName, classCode,student_no, course_id). KEYS(exam_keys, exam_no, course_id). here it is.

Comment: try this line after $this->db->where('exam_no', "$examNo"); $this->db->group_by('exam_keys');

Comment: @GeordyJames an error appeared Severity: Warning
Message  pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: column "student.lastName" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function LINE 1: SELECT "student"."lastName", "student"."firstName", "student... ^

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using two function for showing the data

Use in controller this function

```
public function loadExamKey($examNo)
{
    $data = $this->addExamKey($examNo);
    $data = $this->exam_logs($examNo);
    $data['examKey'] = $this->displayExamKey($examNo);
    $this->load->view('exam_key', $data);
}
```

Use in model this function

```
public function displayExamKeys($examNo)
{
    $this->db->select('student.*,keys.exam_key');
    $this->db->from('student');
    $this->db->join('keys', 'student.course_id = keys.course_id');
    $this->db->where('student.exam_no', $examNo);
    $this->db->group_by('exam_no');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: No it's different, the one in the controller is just to load the displayExamKeys function in the model. But I already edited it, and removed the displayExamKey() in controller but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your join clause. The rest of the code looks good. Try to update the join clause as below:

```
$this->db->join('keys', 'student.course_id = keys.course_id', 'left');
```

If is not working, try to visualize your query using:

```
print_r($query);
```

or by enabling the profiler:

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
```

Comment: It's not working. I used print_r(), it also shows duplication of data and wrong assignment of exam keys.